# Is there a way to use method 'orElseGet' of 'Optional' to create a new list when it is null?

Tags: java, option-type

Say we have a class in the structure as below:

```
class Resource{
   String id; 
   String name;
   List<String> friends;
}
```

Is there a way to get the list using 'Optional' in this way:

```
Optional.of(resource.getFriends()).map(friends -> {
    friends.add("John");
    return friends;
}).orElseGet(
    //do something here.
)
```

A new list is expected if there was no one before.

Comment: why do you need an `Optional` even here? what do you mean by negative to judge a list? With the current piece of code, the only usage that seems feasible could be as: `Optional.of(resource.getFriends()).map(r -> r.add("John")).orElse(false)`

Comment: You need to give us more to work with. You know `r.add("John")` returns `boolean` right? So the Optional is a `Stream<Boolean>`. If you meant to get a `List`, then insted of `map()` wrapped by 'Optilonal` did you mean `forEach()` followed by `collect(Collectors.toList())`?

Comment: If `friends` was `null` before, do you want the newly created list assigned to it?

Comment: I am thinking maybe [`Objects.requireNonNullElse​( T obj , T defaultObj )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse(T,T)) or [`Objects.requireNonNullElseGet​( T obj , Supplier< ? extends T > supplier )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElseGet(T,java.util.function.Supplier)). But I cannot get it to work myself.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I've updated the code according to your feedback. @Naman

Comment: I've checked again the code and found that the description of my question here is correct, but the code is not, so I've modifed the code. @MarkJeronimus

Comment: You are right. This is exactly what I want. @OleV.V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your more precise functional requirements. I present a couple of options.

If you just want a list that contains the friends of a resource and John:

```
    List<String> listWithJohn = Optional.ofNullable(resource.getFriends())
            .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
    listWithJohn.add("John");
```

As Basil Bourque mentioned in a comment, since Java 9 the list initialization can instead be done using `Objects.requireNonNullElseGet`:

```
    List<String> listWithJohn
            = Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(resource.getFriends(), ArrayList::new);
```

If instead you want John added to the friends of the resource, I suggest that the `getFriends` method is where to edit:

```
/** @return The list of friends, not null */
public List<String> getFriends() {
    if (friends == null) {
        friends = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return friends;
}
```

Returning the list itself makes resources vulnerable to callers modifying their friends lists unwantedly and unpredictably at any later time, though. Often one wishes to return a copy of the list or an unmodifiable view of it instead (preventing the caller from adding John as friend). In this case resources could have an `addFriend` method for adding friends.

**EDIT:**

> is there a way to make in only one lambda code line?

```
    friends = friends == null ? new ArrayList<>() : friends;
    return friends;
```

But I would find it less readable (and there’s no lambda there, it’s just a one-liner). Or if you want it completely cryptic:

```
    return friends = friends == null ? new ArrayList<>() : friends;
```

Not recommended.

Comment: At first and foremost, thank you, Ole. To be honest, the current code I put in my program is the last one you listed above, i.e. a classic way to make it. The 1st and 2nd piece of code listed in your reply are good ones as well. Because I think the one main purpose that lambda is employed is to get our goal with less code. (Less is more, right? ^.^), so is there a way to make in only one lambda code line?

Comment: `friends = friends == null ? new ArrayList<>() : friends;`. But I would find it less readable.

Comment: I got you, and I believe it is less readable as well. All in all, thank you again.